# Showing that the category of epimorphisms with same codomain in an abelian category is cofiltrant

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

This is part (i) of exercise 1.7 in Kashiwara and Schapira's "Sheaves on Manifolds".

> Let $\mathcal C$ be an abelian category.
> For any object $Z$ of $\mathcal C$, let $\mathcal P(Z)$ be the category whose objects are the epimorphisms $f:Z'\to Z$, a morphism $(f:Z'\to Z) \to (f':Z''\to Z)$ being defined by $h:Z'\to Z''$ with $f'\circ h = f$. Prove that $\mathcal P(Z)$ is cofiltrant, that is, $\mathcal P(Z)^°$ is filtrant.

In other words, for any object $Z\in\mathcal C$, $\mathcal P(Z)$ is the full subcategory of $\mathcal C/Z$ where we only keep the epimorphisms.

In the book, a filtrant category is defined as follow :

> A category $\mathcal I$ is called filtrant if it satisfies the following conditions.
>
> - For any $i,j\in\text{Ob}(\mathcal I)$, there exists $k\in\text{Ob}(\mathcal I)$ and morphisms $i\to k$ and $j\to k$.
> - For any two morphisms $f,g\in\text{Hom}_{\mathcal I}(i,j)$, there exists a morphism $h:j\to k$ such that $h\circ f = h\circ g$.

So $\mathcal P(Z)$ is cofiltrant if and only if :

- For any two epimorphisms $f:Z'\to Z$ and $f':Z''\to Z$, there exists an object $W$ and two morphisms $h:W\to Z'$ and $h':W\to Z''$ such that $f\circ h = f'\circ h'$ and is an epimorphism.
- For any epimorphism $f:Z'\to Z$ and any two morphisms $h,h':Z''\to Z'$ such that $f\circ h = f\circ h'$ is an epimorphism, there exists a morphism $k:W\to Z''$ such that $h\circ k = h'\circ k$ and $f\circ h\circ k$ is an epimorphism.

<s>The first condition is true since one can take the pullback $W = Z'\times_Z Z''$, which always exists since $\mathcal C$ is abelian :</s>

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
Z'\times_ZZ'' @>{h}>> Z'\\
@V{h'}VV @VV{f}V\\
Z'' @>>{f'}> Z
\end{CD}
And every arrow here is an epimorphism.

Edit: pullback diagrams preserve monomorphisms, not epimorphisms; so I still haven't shown that this first condition is true.

I have been struggling with the second condition, and I even think I found a counter-example.

Suppose that $k:W\to Z''$ is such that $h\circ k = h'\circ k$, then $(h-h')\circ k = 0$, so $k$ factors through the canonical morphism $\text{Ker} (h-h')\to Z''$. Then, if $f\circ h\circ k$ is an epimorphism, the composition $\text{Ker}(h-h')\to Z'' \xrightarrow{h} Z' \xrightarrow{f} Z$ has to be an epimorphism too.

Now, suppose $\mathcal C$ is the category $\mathfrak{Ab}$ of abelian groups. Pick $Z = \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, $Z' = Z'' = \mathbb Z$ with $f$ the projection $\mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, and $h,h':\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z$ given by $h(n) = 3n$ and $h'(n) = 9n$. Then $f\circ h = f\circ h' = f$, but $\text{Ker}(h'-h) = 0$, so $\text{Ker}(h'-h)\to Z''\to Z'\to Z$ is obviously not an epimorphism.

Where did I go wrong, and if I didn't, what would be the correct statement to prove?
The goal of the entire exercise is to show that some functors from $\mathcal C$ to $\mathfrak{Ab}$ are all exact, and that two morphisms are equal (resp. a sequence is exact) if their images by all of these functors are simultaneously equal (resp. the images of the sequence by all of the functors are all exact):

> For $X\in\text{Ob}(\mathcal C)$, set $\tilde h_Z(X) = \lim_{\mathcal P(Z)} \text{Hom} (Z', X)$, where $\text{Hom}(Z', X)$ is the functor from $\mathcal P(Z)$ to $\mathfrak{Ab}$ which associates $\text{Hom}(Z', X)$ to $f:Z'\to Z$ in
> $\mathcal P(Z)$. Prove that $\tilde h_Z$ is an exact functor from $\mathcal C$ to $\mathfrak{Ab}$, and prove that if $f$ and $f'$ in $\text{Hom}(X, X')$ satisfy $\tilde h_Z(f) = \tilde h_Z(f')$ for all $Z\in\text{Ob}(\mathcal C)$, then $f = f'$. Also prove
> that a sequence in $\mathcal C$ is exact if its image by $\tilde h_Z$ is exact for any $Z\in\text{Ob}(\mathcal C)$. Note that this exercise will allow us to transform many problems on abelian categories to problems on $\mathfrak{Ab}$.